# What's wrong with my javascript mousewheel animation code?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, flexslider, mousewheel

I tried to make website like this: http://www.nominet.uk/

I found a code in jsfiddle that seems perfect for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/6ssRA/1/

But if I make the code my own and create only an html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            * {margin:0; padding:0;}
            body { overflow:hidden;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var winH = $(window).height(),
            $root = $('body, html');

            $('#slider > div').height(winH)

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    //get the current active slide
                    var $active = $('#slider > .active');

                    if(delta < 0) { 
                        //mousewheel down
                        var $next = $active.next();
                        //check if there's a next slide available
                        if($next.length){
                            //animate scrolling to the next slide offset top
                           $root.stop(true).animate({scrollTop:$next.offset().top},'slow');
                           //move also the indicator class 'active'
                                           $next.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        }

                    }else{
                        //mousewheel up
                        var $prev = $active.prev();
                        if($prev.length){
                             //animate scrolling to the previous slide offset top
                            $root.stop(true).animate({scrollTop:$prev.offset().top},'slow'); 
                            $prev.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        }
                    }

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="slide1" class="active">slide 1</div>
            <div id="slide2">slide 2</div>
            <div id="slide3">slide 3</div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code doesn't work. I think the .js including is wrong. What do you think?

Comment: Is there any error pop out on console? Anyway, you just included jquery twice, before the code and at the end of body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var winH = $(window).height(),
    $root = $('body, html');

    // VVVV as you use a selector to find #slider, you should ensure that slider is accessible.
    $('#slider > div').height(winH)
```

These part should also be put into domready, as `#slider` would not be render before `<head>`, you need to access it when it's ready in page. In your linked jsfiddle, the writer just change the load settings to `ondomready`, so those lines are in fact wrapped in another domready callback.

Also, you don't need to include jquery twice, you can remove the one at the end of the body.

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
body { overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            * {margin:0; padding:0;}
            body { overflow:hidden;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              
              var winH = $(window).height(),
              $root = $('body, html');
              
              // As you put the scripts in head. The slider in body is not render at this time, so you
              // need to put this into domready's callback.
              $('#slider > div').height(winH)
              
                $(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    //get the current active slide
                    var $active = $('#slider > .active');

                    if(delta < 0) { 
                        //mousewheel down
                        var $next = $active.next();
                        //check if there's a next slide available
                        if($next.length){
                            //animate scrolling to the next slide offset top
                           $root.stop(true).animate({scrollTop:$next.offset().top},'slow');
                           //move also the indicator class 'active'
                                           $next.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        }

                    }else{
                        //mousewheel up
                        var $prev = $active.prev();
                        if($prev.length){
                             //animate scrolling to the previous slide offset top
                            $root.stop(true).animate({scrollTop:$prev.offset().top},'slow'); 
                            $prev.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        }
                    }

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="slide1" class="active">slide 1</div>
            <div id="slide2">slide 2</div>
            <div id="slide3">slide 3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```